# How do I enable HTML5 prefetching on this page?

Tags: php, html5

Site example:  http://www.ianstuart-bride.com

I currently have this bit of code in header.php, but it does not work as desired:

```
<?php if (is_archive() && ($paged > 1) && ($paged < $wp_query->max_num_pages)) { ?>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>">
    <link rel="prerender" href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>">
<?php } elseif (is_singular()) { ?>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
    <link rel="prerender" href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

The homepage prefetch points to a non-existent page.  I would like to disable prefetching on the homepage.

I want to enable prefetching [on these pages](http://www.ianstuart-bride.com/dress/amalfi/), for the 'Next' dress.

[This is the code for the single dress pages.](http://demo.ianstuart-bride.com/single-dress.txt)

I tried this, but it linked to the current page instead of the next one:

```
    <link rel="prefetch" href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_dress) ?>">
    <link rel="prerender" href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_dress) ?>">
```

Comment: you're setting `$next_dress` after you try to use its value?

Comment: +1 to @Milo just because you're using WordPress doesn't mean that you can suspend cause and effect

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you are putting that code in `header.php`, that is required in the file `single-dress.php` using `get_header()`, and in the same file, *after* about 2 dozen lines, you define the variables you used 2 dozen lines *before*.

So, either your server has an embedded time machine, or your code can't work.

What you have to do is just define variables before you use them.

Probably, instead of messing up your code, and fill your header with a series of `if` / `elseif`, you can separate your logic from your templates.

I'll write a simple class that handles the prefetching. You can save it in a separate file and require it from your `functions.php`.

Please read the inline comments for more explanation.

```
<?php
class My_Theme_Prefetcher {

    public $next_url;
    public $prev_url;

    function setup() {
        global $wp_query;
        // for empty query there is nothing to prefetch 
        if ( ! $wp_query instanceof WP_Query || $wp_query->found_posts <= 0  ) return;
        if ( $wp_query->is_archive() ) {
            // next page URL for archives, that is empty if there is no next page URL
            $this->next_url = get_next_posts_page_link();
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_singular( 'dress' ) ) {
            // if on a single page view for dress CPT, run a query for dress posts
            $this->set_dress_query( $wp_query->get_queried_object_id() );
        }
        // A filter to easily get class instance and access to instance methods and vars
        add_filter( 'my_theme_prefetcher', function() { return $this; } );
        // output the prefetch strings on wp_head
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'output' ) );
    }

    /**
    * Perform a query to get all dresses in same collection,
    * save adjacent post URLs into instance properties
    */
    function set_dress_query( $dressid ) {
        $args =  static::dress_query_args( $dressid );
        if ( empty( $args ) ) return;
        $dress_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $dress_query->found_posts > 0 ) {
            // some dresses found, discover and save adjacent URLs
            $adjacents = static::get_adjacents( $dressid, $dress_query->posts );
            if ( $adjacents['next'] ) 
                $this->next_url = get_permalink( $adjacents['next'] );
            if ( $adjacents['prev'] ) 
                $this->prev_url = get_permalink( $adjacents['prev'] );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Given a current ID and a set of posts, discover adjacent posts
    */
    static function get_adjacents( $current, Array $all ) {
        $adjacents = array( 'prev' => FALSE, 'next' => FALSE );
        if ( is_numeric( $current ) && ! empty( $all ) ) {
            $ids = wp_list_pluck( $all, 'ID' );
            $this_posts = array_search( $current, $ids );
            if ( $this_posts !== FALSE ) {
                $prev_i = $this_posts > 0 ? $this_posts -1 : FALSE;
                $next_i = $this_posts < count( $ids ) - 1 ? $this_posts + 1 : FALSE;
                $previous = $prev_i !== FALSE ? $all[ $prev_i ] : FALSE;
                $next = $next_i !== FALSE ? $all[ $next_i ] : FALSE;
                $adjacents = array( 'prev' => $previous, 'next' => $next );
            }
        }
        return $adjacents;
    }

    /**
    * Output prefetch string on wp_head. Do nothing if no, or invalid, URL is set
    */
    function output() {
        if (
            empty( $this->next_url ) ||
            ! filter_var( $this->next_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL )
        ) return;
        $format = '<link rel="prefetch" href="%1$s"><link rel="prerender" href="%1$s">';
        printf( $format, esc_url( $this->next_url ) );
    }

    /**
    * Returns the args for dress query for a given dress id.
    */
    static function dress_query_args( $dressid ) {
        $collections = get_the_terms( $dressid, 'collections' );
        if ( is_wp_error( $collections ) || empty( $collections ) ) return;
        $term = array_shift( $collections );
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'dress',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array( 'taxonomy' => 'collections', 'terms' => array( $term->term_id ) )
            ),
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'title'
        );
        return $args;
    }

}
```

All the logic is in the class: when `setup()` method is called, the class looks at the current query, and if it is an archive, then setup next URL to next archive page. If the page is for a single dress view, then it runs a query to get all dresses in the same collection, and if found, save adjacent post URLs in instance variables.

Now we need to *launch* the class, i.e. call the `setup()` method on a hook fired *after* the main query is set, but *before* `wp_head()` is called: `'template_include'` will be perfect.

I don't use `template_redirect` here to allow faster redirect if needed (without triggering the additional query). However, `'template_include'` is a filter, so we have to return the current template. Add to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    $prefetcher = new My_Theme_Prefetcher;
    $prefetcher->setup();
    return $template;
} );
```

Now, you have only to be sure in your `header.php` there is the `wp_head()` call and the prefetch links will be added by the class.

There is another task to do. In template file (`single-dress.php`) we need to display adjacent posts links, but we don't need to run another query, because adjacent posts URLs are already saved in the  `My_Theme_Prefetcher` instantiated on `'template_include'`.

So we need to access that instance and the custom filter `'my_theme_prefetcher'` that was created for the scope.

So in the template, you can:

```
<figure class="pinboard">
    <?php

    // here goes your thumbnail image stuff, I will not copy it...

    // get the prefetcher instance and check it
    $prefetcher = apply_filters( 'my_theme_prefetcher', NULL );

    if ( $prefetcher instanceof My_Theme_Prefetcher ) { 
        // we got prefetcher instance, get the urls
        $prev_url = $prefetcher->prev_url ? : FALSE;
        $next_url = $prefetcher->next_url ? : FALSE;
    } else {
        // something goes wrong, try to run the query
        // function that returns arguments is static, so we can access it
        $args = My_Theme_Prefetcher::dress_query_args( $post->ID );
        $dress_by_tax = ! empty( $args ) ? new WP_Query( $args ) : FALSE;
        if ( $dress_by_tax instanceof WP_Query && ! empty( $dress_by_tax->posts ) ) {
            // function that returns adjacent posts is static, so we can access it
            $adjacents = My_Theme_Prefetcher::get_adjacents( $post->ID, $dress_by_tax->posts );
            $next_url = $adjacents['next'] ? get_permalink( $adjacents['next'] ) : FALSE;
            $prev_url = $adjacents['prev'] ? get_permalink( $adjacents['prev'] ) : FALSE;
        } else {
            $next_url = $prev_url = FALSE;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <?php if ( $next_url ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-next arrow block button spaced ribbon">
            <a href="<?php echo $next_url ?>">Next</a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $prev_url ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-prev arrow-left block button spaced ribbon2 left">
            <a href="<?php echo $prev_url ?>">Previous</a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="mask"><span>Click for larger size</span></div>

</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am having trouble getting it to work. I have saved the class file as `prefetch.php` and placed it in `includes\`, as `functions.php` looks [like this](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/4716944). So I am unsure where to add what you said should be added to `functions.php`.

Comment: **1** remove the code you posted from `header.php` **2** save the class in my answer (1st code snippet) in a file `prefetch.php` inside the folder `/includes` in you theme and then in `functions.php` write `include 'includes/prefetch.php';` **3** in `functions.php` also copy and paste the secondo snippent in the answer, the one that start with `add_filter( `. **4** You are done. @paradroid

Comment: I did actually get that far, but it caused a load of code to appear in the wp-admin interface. As the syntax highlighting looks a bit weird in my text editor, I think there maybe errors in the class file.  Also, what about the last code snippet?  Thanks.

Comment: The server has PHP 5.4.6.  The garbled text only appears if signed into wp-admin (which also does not cache or minify in wtc total cache).  [Here is a screenshot](http://www.ianstuart-bride.com/screenshot.png).  It also appears at the top of the wp-admin interface.

Comment: @paradroid seems you have not `<?php` on top of the class file...